# Microsoft Word Macro: Add row with value in first cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to build a macro that selects every table in a document, appends a row and sets the value of the first cell in that row to "Text".

Here is what I have now:

```
Sub AddProofRow()
    Dim t As Table
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
         t.Rows.Add
         NewRow = t.Rows.Last
         NewRow.Cells(t.Rows.Count, 1).Value = "Proof"
    Next
End Sub
```

But, I get errors when I run it, how can I make this work?

Comment: `t.Rows.Add.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Text"` but might need For loop instead of For Each

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
Sub AppendRowWithText()
    ' 24 Apr 2017

    Dim NewRow As Row
    Dim t As Integer

    With ActiveDocument
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            Set NewRow = .Tables(t).Rows.Add
            NewRow.Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:="Text"
        Next t
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This cleared the contents of column 2 in the first table, but did add the intended row. 

Unfortunately, column 2 is important and the tables are imported from an external program - thus they come with data.

Comment: My above code doesn't clear any text in any column of any table. Just to be sure, I tested it again, but you can see that there is no code in the proc that selects or defines any column. Only `NewRow.Cells(1)` is defined or touched. The reason for the data you are losing must be in some other part of your code. I hope this is good news for you :-)

Comment: I'm not saying you programmed it to that, I'm saying that's what happened. You're code is the only macro I have, haha. Word is just.. Buggy.